# How to Sort Data in CSV file in Python 3 using the sorted() function?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort the following data in a CSV file:

```
list_all = ["10","2","113.2","200"]
```

Sounds simple, right?
So I use the following codes to sort it:

```
list_all = ["10","2","113.2","200"]
sortedlist = sorted(list_all)
print(sortedlist)
```

But it doesn't work properly.

This is the output from my function.

```
['10', '113.2', '2', '200']
```

Apparently, it is sorted by the first word in each string only, which is weird. How to solve this?

Comment: Why is that weird?

Comment: hint: is there a way to tell sorted to use the float representation of each?

Comment: @PythonNWB It definitely isn't a bug. Try sorting a list with the floating point values instead of string values, and see what happens for yourself.

Comment: That's how lexicographic sorting works, it's not a bug in `sorted()`.

Comment: sortedlist = sorted(list_all, key=lambda row: float(row)) This works for CSV file. For any of you experiencing this issue, it mainly arises from the string type of the data in CSV file. Therefore, by converting the type from to , the problem is solved. Thank you for everyone's contribution below! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in that lists are strings, so they are sorted lexicographically. If you want to sort them by their numeric values, you could use a custom sorting key:

```
sorted(list_all, key = lambda x : float(x))
```

**EDIT:**
As aws_apprentice commented, you could just pass a function as the sorting key and make this call a bit more concise:

```
sorted(list_all, key = float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort `str` types, not `int` or `float`.

```
>>> list_all = [10,2,113.2,200]
>>> sortedlist = sorted(list_all)
>>> print(sortedlist)
[2, 10, 113.2, 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_all = ["10","2","113.2","200"]
list_all.sort(key = float) 
print(list_all)
```

Comment: this sorts the list in place, is that what OP wants? also doesn't hurt to include an explanation

Answer (score 0):

It's because its sorting its contents like `strings` (because that's what they are), you could sort them to by their `float` representation using sorted argument `key`.

```
list_all = ["10","2","113.2","200"]
sortedlist = sorted(list_all, key=float)

print(sortedlist) # --> ['2', '10', '113.2', '200']
```

Answer (score -1):

Python interprets anything inside quotations ' or double quotations " as the String type.
So the numbers you have written are not numbers, are just words!

```
sorted()
```

on strings then, works according to the characters.
Just remove the quotations:

```
list_all = [10,2,113.2,200]
```

Comment: don’t assume that the final output OP wants is floats/integers

Comment: If the list is in a csv file, how do you remove the quotation and turn it from string type into number?

Comment: @PythonNWB you can use `list_all.append(float(row[8]))` when reading from the csv file